# HTTP 404.0 Error Local IIS Site

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I have several IIS sites running on my local machine running IIS 8. 3 of the sites work perfectly fine, the 4th returns a 404.0 Error:

```
"HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. "
```

I have tried everything I can think of but nothing will work.  To save people some time I will list some of the things I tried:

- Adding UrlRoutingModule to my Web.config
- Removing the WebDAVModule
- Adding ExtentionlessURLHandlers

I have also confirmed that the path is correct and the site is in the correct application pool.  I am running out of things to try everything I see on the web seems to say one of these things I tried will fixed it but it hasn't.  My IIS local web server seems to be installed corrected as my other sites work fine, please help!!

Comment: A bit of additional info, when I point to Application I created to the directory of another site it works.  So I feel like it is an issue within the project itself not necessarily IIS.  I've scoured over the web.config and don't see any issues there though...not sure what else to at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a very frustrating day I solved my issue, and it was really due to my last of MVC routing knowledge.  I was attempting to navigate to "localhost/example" which had not controller routing associated with it because I had no home controller.  I either needed to map a home controller to it, change the default controller to map to one of my existing controllers, or the easiest fix was to navigate to "localhost/example/controllername" where "controllername" is the name of the controller that I wanted to start at.  I hope this can save someone else hours of time.